# Printing a dictionary nicely in Xcode

Tags: xcode, debugging

Is there a way to nicely print dictionaries in XCode during debugging? Selecting print description to console is ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Category on NSDictionary and override `- (NSString *)description`.

(This way it automagically applies to all your existing NSDictionaries)

Below is a sample formatting, but you could change it to look like anything you want.

```
//  NSDictionary+NicePrint.h 
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NSDictionary (NicePrint)
@end

//  NSDictionary+NicePrint.m
#import "NSDictionary+NicePrint.h"
@implementation NSDictionary (NicePrint)

- (NSString *)description
{
    NSMutableString *output = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [self enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        [output appendFormat:@"%@ => %@\n", key, obj];
    }];

    return [NSString stringWithString:output];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass NSDictionary and override the -(NSString*)description function of NSObject.

Take you 5 minutes.

Comment: Then I'd have to change the class of all of my dictionaries which is too high a price

Comment: Find "NSDictionary", replace with "NSNewDictionary". Easy in Xcode 3, super trivial in 4 with the preview mode.  So 6 minutes.